# Proving an inequality without using $ AM\geq GM$

Tags: inequality

I was trying to do this question. Let $a_1\times a_2\times a_3\times ....\times a_n = 1$ where all ai are positive real numbers. We have to prove that

$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)....(1+a_n) \geq 2^n$$

How to go about proving this since we **can't** use $ AM\geq GM$? Although this inequality seems obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the minimum value of $(1 + a_1)(1 + a_2). . .(1 + a_n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547505/what-is-the-minimum-value-of-1-a-11-a-2-1-a-n) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(1%2Ba_1)(1%2Ba_2)....(1%2Ba_n)%20%5Cgeq%202%5En.%24)

Comment: Umm, aren't they all using AM-GM??

Comment: There are many ways to show that $1+a_k \geq 2\sqrt{a_k}$, AM-GM is only one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I wanted probably something using induction. But AM-GM is not be used at all. That was the problem.

Comment: Here is a proof by induction: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2859135/42969, but it actually mimics the inductive proof of the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Is that proof using strong induction?Edit: Ok never mind. I am still trying to understand that proof.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^2\geq0$ (square of a real number $\geq0$)

$(1-\sqrt{a_1})^2\geq 0 \implies 1+a_1\geq 2\sqrt{a_1}$

$(1-\sqrt{a_2})^2\geq 0 \implies 1+a_2\geq 2\sqrt{a_2}$

.
.
.

$(1-\sqrt{a_n})^2\geq 0 \implies 1+a_n\geq 2\sqrt{a_n}$

Then

$(1+a_1) \times (1+a_2) \times .... \times (1+a_n)= 2\sqrt{a_1} \times 2\sqrt{a_2} \times ...\times 2\sqrt{a_n} = 2^n \times \sqrt{a_1a_2...a_n}=2^n$

Comment: First of all the inequalities are wrong $(1-\sqrt{a})^2\ge0\implies1+a\ge2\sqrt{a}$ not $2a$, as you have written. Also $1+a_\ge2\sqrt{a}$ is nothing but the AM-GM inequality!

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't notice. Is anything possible using induction then?? I can't find an inductive proof anywhere.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 I am going to try for induction that (per QED's comment) avoids even the *hint* of AM-GM.  If I come up with something, I'll post a 2nd answer.  In the meantime, I reversed the downvote.  It could be argued that QED's criticism is still applicable, however.

Comment: https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2017/06/14/why-is-a%C2%B2-b%C2%B2-%E2%89%A5-2ab/   please check this one AM-GM is different

Comment: What are you implying?

Comment: Square of a number $ \geq 0$

Comment: Yeah,but, I feel like as QED said above, it can be argued that it uses AM-GM somehow. The answer Martin gave above, I need something like that. No trace of AM-GM at all.I might be wrong as well.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 I was going to **try** to craft an induction proof, but the question has been closed.  However, I can offer this *partial auxiliary* to Lion Heart's answer that should satisfy QED's comment: Let $f(x) = 1 + x - 2(x)^{(1/2)} : x > 0.~$ Then $f'(x) = 1 - (x)^{(-1/2)}~$ and $~f''(x) = (1/2) \times (x)^{(-3/2)}.~$ Here we have that as $x \to 0^{+}, f(x) \to 1~$ and $~f(1) = 0.~$ The sole value for $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$ is $x=1~$ and $~f''(1) > 0.~$ Therefore $f(x)$ has an absolute minimum throughout $(0, \infty)~$
at $~x=1~$. Therefore for $~x > 0, ~(1 + x) \geq (x)^{(1/2)}.$

Comment: @QED *so there*

Comment: That's calculus. You mentioned you would give inductive proof above. Why?Although Its good enough. Thanks.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 I used Calculus rather than any *hint* of AM-GM **solely** to satisfy QED's criticism.  Further, ignoring *how* one concludes that $(1+x) \geq 2\sqrt{x}$, **even if** I had conjured an inductive proof for the **remainder** of the demonstration, I would still have regarded my conjuring as **inferior** to the remainder of Lion Heart's answer.  Therefore, my sole motive in attempting induction on the remainder of the demonstration was simply to see if it was possible.

Comment: @nmnsharma_007 For the portion of the demonstration where I used Calculus, it was **never** my intention to *attempt* induction on **that portion** of the demonstration.